# Text-wrap in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-wrap

I typed out text in 14pt.  I then typed another letter in 131pt out.  I was hoping to have my 14pt text wrap around the 131pt character...but to no avail!  I clicked on both items (and my 131pt. letter was above the layer for the other text) and clicked on "Text Wrap > Make".  Nothing happens.
Am i not doing this correctly?  I even tried to follow a tutorial...it seems so obvious and simple...yet might this be a bug in CS6?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Set the **area type** box - you **must click-drag with the type tool** to create a box, then insert the text into the box.
- set the drop cap character
- if you want the wrap to be rectangular around the drop cap. Select the drop cap and choose Object > Text Wrap > Make

[image: live type]

- if you want the area type to wrap the contour of the drop cap - Select the drop cap and choose Type > Create Outlines, then choose Object > Text Wrap > Make

[image: contour]

When applying a text wrap, you only want to **select the object to be wrapped**. Nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the wrap object (in this case the outlined letter T) is above the text, and in the same layer.