# How to insert image in a text paragraph without overlapping the text in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, images

Sorry my question is kinda fuzzy, I can't construct the proper sentence for my question. Well here is a screenshot of what I wanted to do:

[image]

Basically what I want to do is to insert an image in my text paragraph but I want it not to overlap but just to follow/adjust to the edge of the image (just like in microsoft word text wrapping).

Thank you! One illustrator newbie lad here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/text-wrap-in-illustrator-cs6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create any shape you want and choose "Area Type Tool" from the type panel,

Next, click on the shape you have created and start typing.

It is clear that you should place your images first and after that to create the shape which borders with the images and other objects:

[image]

or... this one :)))

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You did great in showing me the solution!

Answer (score 0):

First you should type your text paragraph. Then place your image on the text box. Then select both text paragraph and image. Go to the Object menu > Text Wrap > Make. It will do your magic :)